# is this patent US20100122390 still in effect

Tags: us20100122390

In reference to the patent: [US20100122390](https://www.google.com/patents/US20100122390)

Answer (score 1):

First, note the **publication type** is *application*, not *patent*.

To see the status of the application, you can go to [USPTO PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair), put in the application number "20100122390", select the "Publication Number" radio button, and select "Search".

The application went through several rejections and amendment. On 2010-10-12, a final rejection was issued. On 2011-09-05, the application was deemed **abandoned** due to failure to respond to the last rejection.

If you select the Image File Wrapper tab, you can retrieve text of the last rejection, The examiner cited patent application [2006/0090249](https://www.google.com.tw/patents/US20060090249) by Rodriguez and application [2007/0250978](https://www.google.com.tw/patents/US20070250978) by Peterson as prior art, and concluded the amended claims were unpatentable under [U.S.C. 103(a)](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2141.html).

If you want to know if your creation infringes on any patent, you should check the patent application cited by the examiner.